# Change react-bootstrap OverlayTrigger Popover's content while displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am using react-boostrap's Popover with the OverlayTrigger class. My issue is that when I change the content on the Popover while it is displayed, it is properly resized but the position gets wrong. The popover maintains its top left corner position even if it is not aligned anymore with the OverlayTrigger

Here is what I am talking about:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I am using in my render function, it's pretty straightforward:

```
const popover = (
        <Popover id={this.props.htKey} >
            {this.state.content}
        </Popover>
);

return (
            <OverlayTrigger
                trigger={["hover", "focus"]}
                delayShow={200}
                placement="top"
                overlay={popover}
                onEntered={this.startExtendTimer}
                onExited={this.resetContent}
            >
                <span>test</span>
            </OverlayTrigger>


 );
```

The `startExtenTimer` calls a timeout that changes `this.state.content` after a few seconds (therefore resulting in the issue that I show on the picture)

How can I change the content of the popover while keeping the correct alignment?

Comment: Post some code...

Comment: I added some code but I don't think it helps, it's a very basic script.

Comment: react-bootstrap calculates the position when the component is mounted. You would have to somehow trigger a recalculation on your end. Have a look at how the internal code works (react-bootstrap.js:15222)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution here:

Similar question: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1438

Answer: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/pull/42

You can basically add a `shouldUpdatePosition` props to a Overlay component.

```
<Overlay ... shouldUpdatePosition={true}  >
```

My current issue with it is that I have an ugly delay before the repositioning. I am looking into it and will update if I found a solution

UPDATE: To remove this delay, I just had to immediately re-render the component holding the Overlay when the said overlay content get updated.

Comment: I cannot find that option in the documentation https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/?

Comment: @Andrei Cioara, the option is not documented, as explained in the links. But it does exist.

Comment: I cannot get it to work on the OveralyTrigger. Does it only exit on the Overlay?

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this with OverlayTrigger? @AndreiCioara

Comment: So, anyone was able to make that work with OverlayTrigger?